Derive white balance matrix operator in YUV space
Assume that the white balance matrix operator in RGB space is $$W=\begin{bmatrix}
    \alpha &0 &0 \\
    0 & \beta & 0 \\
    0&0&\gamma
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the constants are determined based on RGB data and so on. If we also know the conversion matrix RGB $\to$ YUV, call it $C$, then the white balance operator in YUV space, $T$ can be derived as $$W=C^{-1}TC$$ $$CWC^{-1}=T$$
I don't think this is correct. According to my course lecturer, after extending the YUV coordinates to $4\times1$ column vectors, the matrix $T$ should look like $$T=\begin{bmatrix}
    1&0&0&0 \\
    0&1&0&v \\
    0&0&1&b\\
    0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $v,b$ are to be determind. Even after adjusting matrices $W$ and $C$ for the extended coordinates, the matrix $T=CWC^{-1}$ doesn't look anything like above. How should $T$ be derived when $C$ and $W$ are given?
